# Build error on referencing Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.DLL

Tags: c#, .net, azure, blob, windows-phone-8.1

I am getting the following error while building my Windows Azure Mobile Services based WP8.1 project. I've tried both .NET4 and .NET4.5

> c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows
>   Azure\AzCopy\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll : warning CS1684:
>   Reference to type 'System.IO.FileMode' claims it is defined in
>   'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\WindowsPhoneApp\v8.1\mscorlib.dll', but
>   it could not be found

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Hi Kunal are you sure you are referencing the right library of windowsAzure.storage that is compatible with the windows phone?

Comment: `install-package WindowsAzure.Storage` in the packagemanager-console will do the trick. But first delete all you other references to the `WindowsAzure.Storage`

Comment: Thanks @JordyvanEijk . When I install the package, the package manager console says its successfully referenced but it doesn't show in "References" folder. So I use the DLL file present in "Program Files/Microsoft SDK"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is the right one. because it is part of the Microsoft SDK which in my oppinion is only for the Windows platform but i can be wrong on this point. I think you need a specific one for Windows Phone take a look at [this website](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/mobile-services/) and select the platform Windows Phone, here you will find more information about Azure and Windows Phone.

I hope this helps.